# XLForm blank on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios7, xlform

I can't find any mention of why forms wouldn't be rendering on iOS 7.1 when they're looking slick on iOS 8. The only glimmer of hope I have is that in one I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewWillAppear`, and that one renders.

I'm using a build of XLForms 2.1.0 from October 2014.

[XLForms integration empty tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969508/xlforms-integration-empty-tableview) may be of use to you if you're having other blank form issues:

Answer (score 4):

I noticed in the XLForm sample project, this pattern within View Controllers:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeForm];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeForm];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initializeForm
{
    // Your form initialization code here
}
```

I was setting up my form in `viewDidLoad`, which must have a different lifecycle when compared to XLForms running on iOS 8.

Comment: Calling [self.tableView reloadData] on viewWillAppear: did the trick.
The view lifecycle definitely changed since iOS 8